# Why can't I use this parameter for Compare of std::sort()?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to sort an std::vector of Meshes (Each with their own transform class and hence location) in ascending order of the distance of their location from the camera (A predefined Vec3).

== renderlist.hpp ==

```
//Includes & guard omitted

typedef std::vector<Object*> ObjectList;
class RenderList
{
public:
    RenderList(Object** objects, unsigned int numObjs, Camera& camRef);
    ObjectList getOrderedObjectList();
    void renderInOrder(Shader& master);
private:
    ObjectList unorderedList;
    Camera* cameraReference;
}
```

== renderlist.cpp ==

```
struct RenderListCompare
{
    Vec3 cp;
    RenderListCompare(Vec3 camPos)
    {
        cp = camPos;
    }
    bool compare(Object* obj1, Object* obj2)
    {
        Vec3 pos1 = obj1->getTransform().getTranslate();
        Vec3 pos2 = obj2->getTransform().getTranslate();
        return (pos1.distance(cp) > pos2.distance(cp));
    }
};

RenderList::RenderList(Object** objects, unsigned int numObjs, Camera& camRef)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numObjs; i++)
    {
        this->unorderedList.push_back(objects[i]);
    }
    this->cameraReference = &camRef;
}

void RenderList::getOrderedObjectList()
{
    ObjectList temp = this->unorderedList;
    RenderListCompare rlc(this->cameraReference->getPos());
    std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end(), rlc.compare);
    return temp;
}
```

The problem here is that I'm trying to use `<algorithm>`'s `std::sort` function's Compare parameter to tell it how to order the list (Via distance from camera position), but the struct I'm using for the comparison needed to be instantiated before I used its `compare()` function as a parameter.

An example similar to what I'm trying to do can be found at: [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)
I am getting the following error upon compilation:

```
    renderlist.cpp: In member function 'ObjectList RenderList::getOrderedObjectList()': renderlist.cpp:32:49: error:
    no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector::iterator, std::vector::iterator, )'
        std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end(), rlc.compare);
                                               ^
```

My guess is that I've tried to mimic the link above to achieve a similar affect, but adding extra information to the struct before, which may have lead to a syntax error on my behalf.

Comment: Start with removing the data member and constructor from the compare class. Pass an instance to the sort function.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: What is wrong with the data member and constructor?

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf : I found that renaming the compare function to operator()(Object* obj1, Object* obj2) and passing the instance of the RLC struct into sort did the job perfectly. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: They serve no purpose other than supporting some confusion on the part of the OP. When they're removed that confusion will hopefully be reduced.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: It seems that you have misunderstood the code. There is absolutely nothing wrong with the data member and constructor. The comparator is _"which object, of the two provided, is furthest from <point given at comparator initialisation>?"_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Indeed. Thanks. I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how comparators work. Change your `compare` member function into an `operator()` …

```
struct RenderListCompare
{
   RenderListCompare(const Vec3& camPos)
      : cp(camPos)
   {}

   bool operator()(const Object* obj1, const Object* obj2)
   {
      Vec3 pos1 = obj1->getTransform().getTranslate();
      Vec3 pos2 = obj2->getTransform().getTranslate();
      return (pos1.distance(cp) > pos2.distance(cp));
   }

private:
   const Vec3 cp;
};
```

… and just pass the `RenderListCompare` object to `std::sort`, instead of naming the member function yourself.

```
std::sort(
   temp.begin(),
   temp.end(),
   RenderListCompare(this->cameraReference->getPos())
);
```

Comment: @Cheers I'll thank you not to impose your personal style choice on my answers!

Comment: @Lighness: Writing `this->` is just silly outside a template, and it teaches bad habits to readers.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: You are entitled to your opinion, and I am entitled not to share it! It's bad form to impose your personal style choice on other people's answers. Or shall I go through your answers and rewrite all those silly `auto main() -> int`... :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: In the light of pure curiosity, why does the frequent use of  `this->` get frowned upon fairly often? I picked up the habit from Java, is it worth shaking it to make my code more readable? I tend to make class data members have a same name as constructor parameters, so that's why I continue to use `this->` in C++.

Comment: @Harrand: Well, if you initialise your members properly, you don't need to use `this->` there whether they have the same names as ctor parameters or not. As for the rest ... I don't know. Sometimes opponents of `this->` prefer Hungarian-style `m_` prefixes; sometimes opponents of `this->` prefer no prefixes at all. There doesn't seem to be any consistent, widely-agreed-upon standpoint. I will usually eschew `this->` in my own code where possible, but not in a demonstrating example.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thank you for the insight. I've seen `m_` prefixes used before, although I really dislike them for some reason. I'll consider weening off of `this->`.

Comment: @Harrand: I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: Another option would be using a lambda function. From what I understand, not being able to use a regular class member function for a compare is an issue with std::sort(), std::stable_sort(), std::list::sort(). I'm wondering if qsort() (not a template function) would be able to use a regular member function.

Comment: @rcgldr: You can use `std::bind`. There is no such issue as far as I'm aware.